# UI Router's Resolve and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm curious as to how I would go about using UI Router's resolve with TypeScript.

```
.state("signin.notActivated", <ng.ui.IState> {
                    controller: "SigninCtrl",
                    controllerAs: "signin",
                    url: "/notActivated",
                    resolve: {
                        inProgress: function() {
                            return { formData : null }
                        }
                    }
                })
```

In my controller, I have injected my resolve.

```
constructor(public $state : angular.ui.IState, private inProgress) {
            this.init();                
        }

        private init = () => {
            this.someData = this.inProgress.formData; // error
        }
```

I am getting an unknown provider error, because TypeScript is trying to register it as a service.

[image]

Can this be done?

Comment: TypeScript is not registering anything. This is transpiled to plain javascript, nothing else. I do seem to miss your error though. The only thing I notice in your code is your string reference to the controller class. Normally I use the typescript reference instead, that is without the quotes. Is the javascript as expected?

Comment: @Thomas were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting it like this:

```
static $inject = ['$state', 'inProgress'];
constructor(public $state : angular.ui.IState, private inProgress) {
    this.init();                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're invoking the controller only through the router. Invoking the controller directly from the html through ng-controller directive (`ng-controller="SigninCtrl as signin"` in your case) will not have the inProgress injected and so you will end up in this error.